# Time sync with WiFi

Tags: raspbian, wireless, wifi, ntp

It looks like the `ntpd` doesn't get the correct time with WiFi. My Raspberry Pi's are connected via WiFi dongles (which work without problems) to my network.
The odd thing is, I read that the time should be on "Jan 1, 1970" if it doesn't work correctly. But my time is always on "Jun 13, 2013"...

When I perform the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ntp
```

or wait for a while it gets the right time.
Maybe the `ntpd` starts before the WiFi has connected successfully? Can I change this in an easy way?

I found something similar, but it was for Arch Linux which doesn't help me.

Comment: The Pi saves the current time and date right before it shuts down, and restores this time when it starts up again. This way, the next time it boots up, the time will, let's say, less inaccurate. It's called `fake-hwclock`. That would explain your `Jun 13, 2013` observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add that command (`sudo dpkg-reconfigure ntp`) to the bottom of `.bashrc`.  That way, every time you log in the time will be updated (assuming the WiFi device is connected to the Raspberry Pi and running properly).

1. Make sure you are in the `pi` folder: `$ cd ~`
2. Open up `.bashrc` for configuration: `$ sudo nano .bashrc`
3. Scroll down to the bottom and add the line `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ntp`
4. Exit and save: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

If you are looking for a solution that works on bootup, take a look at [this link](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html). Basic rundown:

1. Create a file for your startup "script": `$ sudo nano /etc/init.d/scriptname`
2. Add the line `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ntp` to your file.
3. Exit and save: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Make the "script" executable: `$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/scriptname`
5. Register script to be run at start-up: `$ sudo update-rc.d scriptname defaults`

Comment: Can't I do this on the Raspberry Pi in a global solution? This way it will only have effect if I log in with the user pi?

Comment: I've edited a link into the answer for running a command on startup.  Take a look there.

Comment: Since I extended the script with the dependencies $all so it will definitely performed after the wifi is setup correct I had to use the command insserv instead of update-rc.d but now it works. thanks!

Comment: @Bagorolin: It would be very helpful to people who come after you if you were to document the whole procedure, including the full commands such as `insserv`, in an answer to your own question. Thanks.

Comment: @dotancohen how do i make code blocks if there is an "#" at the beginning? I can't find something in the help site. And unfortunately I don't have so much time to look for this..

Comment: Code blocks are created by simply indenting the lines with four spaces, and having a blank line before and after the block. Go ahead and post it as best you can, and I'll edit it to format it properly. Thank you Bagorolin!

Comment: I have the same problem but restarting ntp or `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ntp` didn't help